# Good Keyboard/Mice specifications for Daily Office Use

Tags: keyboards, mice

I work at a institution where we need to buy a few keyboards and mices for replacement.

The problem is: we have to do that through a "inverse auction" technique where the interested sellers have to read the specification first and then make the offer. Lowest price win.

We cannot require a product from a specific brand or model, but we can give specifications to be followed.

Just for you to understand the problem, last "inverse auction", the company that won offered  $2 mouses and $5 keyboards that probably wont last much or even be usable.

I would like to find good specifications for mid-tier keyboards and mice to stock up, knowing that we cannot replace these every so often or go to the closest shop and buy a new one.

However, I did not find good standarized metrics for keyboard and mice specifications, so I need community opinion on how to constrain offers to a reasonably good Office standard.

In my research, I've already have gotten some ideas: One guy at Superuser suggested "travel for the keypress, kind of switching, keyroll over" and Cable Lenght.

I also thought about Microsoft's 2 year warranty that usually does not apply to third line chinese branded keyboards, but not sure if that's enought.

Any other hints?

Comment: If you want to force a fairly expensive mouse, specify Omron switches. Besides that, have got a certain mouse in mind?

Comment: Any that wont break after a few clicks. A logitech is a good pick, but not sure if it has any different configuration from the low quality chinese ones...

Comment: Best I can do is specify Omron switches then. Maybe also specify that it has to be a Philips, Avago, or Pixart sensor. Again, best bet will be to pick a mouse you think is good and then run with that.